# Android : Play Services issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am trying to add google play services in my project when i add

***compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.+'***

---

or lower version my project works fine

when i add

***com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.+*** or **com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1**

i receive an error and the error is:

```
 Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Whereas when i use the above statement it works fine what is the issue can someone explain or give me a way to fix it!!.

***Gradle File is***:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MyPackageName"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
   //i tried 9.+ still receiving same error and also enabled the multidex option but failed



}
```

Comment: check my answer

Comment: It has been asked and answered many times. Please check about Multi Dex. Please do some research before posting the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]when you use google play service library.
first you refer this link: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: @KumailHussain please check this image

Comment: it works : as i am using ads so i have to add only: "    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'"??

Comment: @KumailHussain  yes.this answer helpful to you then please accept this answer or upvote it .

Comment: Sorry i cannot cast a vote but surely will vote when i have access to it

Comment: @KumailHussain ok no problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the Bottom of build.gradle.
     in Module level

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and 
in Project level

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0
```